# How to add a 360 degree panorama view to an android app?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, 360-panorama

Well, I have been searching a way to add a 360 degree panoramic image for now, but for some reason, I was not able to find something useful from the internet. The only thing I found was this tutorial was this [Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/android/vrview)https://youtu.be/gnDa-fvEyUk, which, unfortunately, is in Kotlin. So hope you guys would help me sort this.

Well, by the way I found this documentaion; however, I was not able to comprehend much from this, especially the java part. It seems the layout part is easy(all about adding VRPanorama view[Google VR documentation](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/android/vrview)
Thanks in advance.
PS: I am gonna do it in a fragment, so if possible, please show me the way of fragments.

EDIT: In general, what I want to add is 360-degree to one of my fragments that is similar to the video I shared. I have already added the dependencies and wrote the code for the layout file(the same as the tutorial), and also, I am more interested in URL way. After some searching, again I found something which might be helpful(Still Kotlin though). [Tutorial](https://itnext.io/android-360-panorama-cedbfb47a9e)

Comment: Well the link you provided has the tutorial in JAVA, and not Kotlin. So can you please elaborate your problem a bit.

Comment: Indeed, I did provide the wrong link, now I have edited. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: But the previous link of yours is correct, what seems to be the problem then with the prev video

Comment: The previous video was not about 360-degree panorama but vertical and horizontal ones, which are apparently not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve image from the URL, all you should do is add a invisible i.e gone imageview in the xml and using glide load the image in that view and from the view retrieve that image as drawable and convert it to Bitmap and then load that view in the VR's SDK method and load it.

That's it, and for the fragment part all you have to do is define the VR and Image views in the fragment and then write the required code in the fragments class.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "load that view in the VR's SDK method and load it" ? As I am a newbie, I cannot quite catch what you are implying. Yes, I know how to load simple imageviews with glide, but how can I achieve that for 360-degree panorama? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: vrPanoramaView.loadImageFromBitmap(resource, option), the loadImageFromBitmap() is the method that I am talking about. This method is used to load the image in the VR view and make it a VR type image.